# Tensorflow model slower than in the documentation

Tags: tensorflow

I am using the code at: https://keras.io/examples/imdb_fasttext/ for testing the performance of my PC. I have GTX 2060, Ubuntu 18.04, Tensorflow 2.0, Cuda 10.1, cuDNN7.6. I got 22 secs/epoch using the bi-grams, however according to this page, only 2 secs/epoch are needed in a GTx 980M GPU. I was hoping to have a second per epoch with my configuration.

Can anyone help me understand what could be the issue?

Many thanks,
Roxana